# Update String Value Using Live Data

Tags: android, data-binding, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-jetpack

I am Implementing the Data Binding with Live Data Architecture . I done all the stuff but I am unable to find where i have to update the response value in fragment.
I made a button and on button click I am able to send the data to server and get the response . But My problem is How the msg value or Success value update in fragment. My observer not called when value is update . Is there anything i am doing wrong implementation . Thanks in advance.

**My Fragment**

```
  **Oncreate Method**
            {        signUpViewModel=ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SignUpViewModel.class);
                observeViewModel(signUpViewModel);
              return view;
            }

//my observe class
            private void observeViewModel(SignUpViewModel signinViewModel) {
                    if (signinViewModel.getmessage() != null) {
                        signinViewModel.getmessage().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onChanged(@Nullable String msg) {
                                if (msg != null) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

//button clicked     
            public void onSignUpClicked(View view)
            {   
     signUpViewModel.registerUser(userFName, userLName, userEmail,userPassword);
                    }
```

**SignUpViewModel.class**

```
public class SignUpViewModel extends ViewModel{
    private LoginFragmentRepository loginFragmentRepository;
    private LiveData<String> sucessMsg;
    String signUpMsg;

    public  void registerUser(String userFName, String userLName, String userEmail, String userPassword) {
       loginFragmentRepository=new LoginFragmentRepository();
        sucessMsg= loginFragmentRepository.registerUser( userFName,  userLName,  userEmail,  userPassword);
    }

    /**
     * get signup msg
     * @return
     */
    public LiveData<String> getmessage() {
        return sucessMsg;
    }
```

**LoginFragmentRepository**

```
{
    private ApiInterface apiInterface;
    private UserDao userDao;
public LiveData<String> registerUser(String userFName, String userLName, String userEmail, String userPassword) {
        apiInterface = RestApi.getRetroInstance().create(ApiInterface.class);
         final MutableLiveData<String> msg = new MutableLiveData<>();
        Call<SignUpModel> req = apiInterface.registerUser(userFName,userLName,userEmail,userPassword);
        req.enqueue(new Callback<SignUpModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SignUpModel> call, Response<SignUpModel> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                  //update this value in fragment
                    msg.postValue(response.body().getData());
                    //getReceipesListDataResponseMutableLiveData.setValue(NetworkResponse.success(receipes));
                } else {
                    msg.postValue("Please check your network connection");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SignUpModel> call, Throwable t) {
                msg.postValue("Please check your network connection");
            }
        });
        return msg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onCreateView method is called once, the following condition is true and you never register an observable:

```
if (signinViewModel.getmessage() != null) {
                        signinViewModel.getmessage().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onChanged(@Nullable String msg) {
                                if (msg != null) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

What I recommend you to do is this. Change the registerUser  method in your view model to:

```
 public  LiveData<String> registerUser(String userFName, String userLName, String userEmail, String userPassword) {
       loginFragmentRepository=new LoginFragmentRepository();
       return loginFragmentRepository.registerUser( userFName,  userLName,  userEmail,  userPassword);
    }
```

And then in your fragment, observe when you click the button.

```
public void onSignUpClicked(View view)
            {   
     signUpViewModel.registerUser(userFName, userLName, userEmail,userPassword).observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onChanged(@Nullable String msg) {
                                if (msg != null) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

Comment: Ok, let me check this .

Comment: Thanks , Yes on button click working good . I placed in wrong way.